# Print levels of conditioning variable in heading (strip) on each specific plot in lattice

Tags: r, histogram, lattice, strip

I typed in the following:

```
histogram(~ Raw.no10$Width | Raw.no10$Station * Raw.no10$Year,
  data = Raw.no10, layout = c(4, 2), nin = 30, xlab = "Prosomal Width (mm)",
  strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white'), ylab = "Frequencies", tick = -1, col = 'grey')
```

On the top of each small graph, it shows "Raw.no10$Year" instead of a specific year, such as 2014.

So, I changed to the following:

```
histogram(~ Raw.no10$Width | Raw.no10$Station * Raw.no10$Year,
  data = Raw.no10, layout = c(4, 2), nin = 30, xlab = "Prosomal Width (mm)",
  strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white', var.name = c("2002", "2014")),
  ylab = "Frequencies", tick = -1, col = 'grey')
```

The top of each small graph now shows "2014" exclusively.  I can't find "2002" in any graphs.

How can I print the value of a conditioning variable in the strip above each panel in these lattice histograms?

Comment: What does `Raw.no10` look like? Does it reside in an existing package? Otherwise can you post the result of `dput(Raw.no10)`, or if too large, something like `head(Raw.no10)`? That way you'll be much more likely to get the help you're looking for. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: One right off the hip: Try calling variables, not vectors (this is why `data` argument is there for). `histogram(~Width | Station * Year, data=Raw.no10...`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Roman.I have tried to do so and hence only the word "Year" shows consistently on all lattice plots....orz

Comment: THanks Dominic. May I please know how to use the dput(Raw.no10)? I have tried to type in this programme language into the R and R said: "Error in dput(head(Raw.no10), 20) : 'file' must be a character string or connection "

Comment: That should be `dput(head(Raw.no10, 20))` since the `20` is an argument to `head`. Then copy and paste what appears in the console after typing in that command.

Answer (score 1):

The lattice plot functions will print the level of the conditioning variables (variables after the `|`) above the panels as long as the conditioning variables are factors. If the conditioning variables are numeric, which is my guess in your case, the values will not be printed *automatically*.

So there are **two ways** to go about answering your request

First, some reproducible data

```
set.seed(123)
histDat <- expand.grid(Station = 1:5, Year = 2009:2014)
histDat$Width <- rnorm(nrow(histDat), 15 + histDat$Station, 5)
```

**1. Change the `strip.levels` argument to `strip.custom`**

Pass the value `c(TRUE, TRUE)` to the `strip.levels` argument in the `strip.custom` function. This will print the levels of the conditioning variables whether or not the underlying variable in your data frame is a factor. It will also print the variable names.

```
histogram(~ Width | Station * Year, data = histDat,
    strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white', strip.levels = c(TRUE, TRUE)),
    ylab = "Frequencies" ,tick = -1, col = 'grey')
```

[image]
 **2. Change the conditioning variable to a factor**

You can change the conditioning variable (`Year` in theis case) to a factor either by altering your data.frame or changing the formula passed to `histogram` as below. This will print the variable level but not the variable name. If you want the variable name, then you should change the value passed to the `strip.names` argument of `strip.custom`.

```
histogram(~ Width | Station * factor(Year), data = histDat,
    strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white', strip.names = c(TRUE, TRUE)),
    ylab = "Frequencies" ,tick = -1, col = 'grey')
```

[image]